# Convert true|false string to boolean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to find the best way|path to achieve this since right now the JSON I'm parsing is small but will grow up fast and will bring a lot of headaches to me. So, I have a JSON like this:

```
{
   "wzSolicitud":{
      "tab1":true,
      "compTab1":[
         "true",
         "false"
      ],
      "tab2":true,
      "tab3":true
   },
   "wzProducto":{
      "tab1":true,
      "tab2":true,
      "tab3":true,
      "tab4":true,
      "tab5":true,
      "tab6":true,
      "tab7":true
   }
}
```

And I'm parsing it as follow:

```
 // I use `estadosWz` because this is what the server side returns
tabsActive = JSON.parse(data.estadosWz[0]);
```

Then for some reason, unknow to me, the result are strings and not bool values so I need to do this for each one:

```
var varToggleTipoTramiteSolObj = tabsActive.wzSolicitud.compTab1[0] === "true" ? true : false,
    varToggleOficinaRegionalSolObj = tabsActive.wzSolicitud.compTab1[1] === "true" ? true : false;
```

And then use `varToggleTipoTramiteSolObj` instead of `tabsActive.wzSolicitud.compTab1[0]`, can any suggest me another solution than this one? How do I parse and convert strings values to boolean ones?

Comment: What you're doing is the right way. It looks like the problem is in the code that creates the JSON object in the first place.

Comment: @ArunPJohny by changing the format to `"tab1":"true"` what do I achieve? I'm not follow you

Comment: @Barmar and what do you suggest me on that case? I mean what should be the right JSON to return from the server side?

Comment: @ReynierPM sorry.. I misread the question... the problem is in the array value `compTab1`.... it should be `"compTab1":[
         true,
         false
      ]`... not that array is an array of strings.... so you need to change the serverside code which is generating the json

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah, you're right by changing that all works my bad and I didn't get it before, thanks

Comment: @ReynierPM The server should return an array of booleans, not an array of strings.

Comment: If you post the server code, we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar don't worry about that part, I have this string on the DB `{ "wzSolicitud": {"tab1": true,"compTab1": [true,false],"tab2": true,"tab3": true},"wzProducto": {"tab1": true,"tab2": true,"tab3": true,"tab4": true,"tab5": true,"tab6": true,"tab7": true}}` and I just read it using Symfony and using HttpFoundation component I return a JsonResponse that's all

Comment: I don't understand why it returns correct booleans in the object properties, but not in the array. Sounds like a Symfony misfeature.

Comment: @Barmar no, Symfony is right I just fixed the main string on the database based on ArunPJhonny suggestion ;)

Comment: I'm confused now. Is that comment from before or after you fixed it?

Comment: @Barmar [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613722/convert-truefalse-string-to-boolean-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment43649558_27613722) comment is related to this comment "If you post the server code, we can help you fix it" from you and yes it was after I fixed the string at DB